# How do I use JavaScript (or something like PHP or ASP) to receive requests to open a socket?

Tags: javascript, sockets

I've seen many explanations all over the internet on how to use JavaScript to open an HTML5 WebSocket to a server. But I don't want to do that. I want this to *receive* connections, and act maybe a bit like a server itself. Is there any way to do this in JavaScript, or something similar, or a preprocesser like PHP or ASP?

Comment: http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Socket-Programming-With-PHP/ , http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a server-side software to do this. If you want to write your server in javascript, you should take a look at [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/). Also, here is a [great blog post](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-real-time-coffeescript-web-applications-with-socketstream/) that will help you get started with Node.js and sockets (to communicate between server and browser)